# Replace multiple underscore with space or new line on paragraph using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hi i have a data scraped from a website and i want to clean its paragraph and i dont how can i remove multiple underscore and replace it with space or new line.

Here is the sample paragraph I scraped using cheerio.js

```
The future of mobile gameplay is War Games!_______________________________________ATTENTION ALL PLAYERS! We’d love to hear your feedback to help us improve the game. To leave feedback visit here.
```

Then I want this to be like this.

```
The future of mobile gameplay is War Games!
ATTENTION ALL PLAYERS! We’d love to hear your feedback to help us improve the game. To leave feedback visit here.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const text = "The future of mobile gameplay is War Games!_______________________________________ATTENTION ALL PLAYERS! We’d love to hear your feedback to help us improve the game. To leave feedback visit here.";

let newstr = text.replace(/\_+/i, "\n");
console.log(newstr);
```

The `\_+` part will match one or more "_" and replace everything with a newline.

Comment: can i have a follow up question on this? how can i add this '\n' to that regex.

Comment: Good answer. BTW an underscore is not a special character in regex and you do not need to espace it with a backslash. The `i` option will be unnecessary as well. It may be better to add `g` option considering the case the sentense contains multiple sequences of underscores. Cheers.